# Visual Studio font and color setting

Tags: visual-studio-2010, settings, background-color

I don't know why this is bothering me so much, but I'm having a hard time figuring out what controls the background color for html attribute tags in Visual Studio 2010.

Here's a screenshot from my setup, with arrows pointing at some of the offenders:

[image]

You can see how it's a slightly lighter color, and it's bugging me to no end :D

If you know which setting controls this, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is controlled by the "HTML Attribute Name" item. For just about each identifier that you can set a custom foreground color, you can also set a custom background color. Generally, you won't want a custom background color, so you set the "item background" to "Default", which generally means "inherit the background color from the setting for "Plain Text".

[image]

Although, I can barely see the difference between the colors in your screen shot. I guess that just goes to show how poorly calibrated my second LCD screen is…

Comment: It turns out I had to do a restart for some reason before that color change took effect (although other changes occurred without a restart).  But this is the right answer, so you win!

Comment: +1 for differentiating foreground and background schemes in VS